# How to add pdf attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, pdf

I have created one attribute "text field" and added

```
<a href="{{media url='wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/Data_sheets/1.pdf'}}"  target="_blank">Kaifeng Products Overview </a>
```

in text field but link is not getting created .

I am getting this url:

> http://eeusa.abc.com/%7B%7Bmedia%20url='wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/Data_sheets/1.pdf'%7D%7D

Comment: let me know whether you would like to add this pdf at cms page?

Comment: actually that {{media url='wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/Data_sheets/1.pdf'}}" will used in cms and static blocks